# How to check that I can SUM values of given type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

In our application we have number of AggregatorTypes (idea copied from SQL Server)
i.e. MinAggregator MaxAggregator, CountAggregator, And SumAggregator.

Now I should check if Aggregator supports type of provided values. For Count it is not important. For Max and Min I use checking for IComparable. 
But what to use for SUM?
I tried Converter but it also supports string.

Why there is no ISummable :)

Also IsNumeric like checking is not a solution for me. For example TimeSpan also can sum.

Comment: Well what is a summation in you context. There's is kind of a ISummable. All the types that implement the '+' operator can be added resulting in the sum of the two operands but you state that for certain types that can be summarized you do not want them to appear to be summarizable.

Comment: yes I know that, string implement '+' but it is not summation it is _concatenation_

Comment: Actually, `string` **does not** have a + operator. That interpretation is provided entirely by the C# compiler (as defined in the C# spec, it maps to `string.Concat`).

Comment: Summable for me is that:
if I can add some value and than remove same value, result remains same as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample IsSummable method

```
public bool IsSummable(Type type)
try
{
  ParameterExpression paramA = Expression.Parameter(type, "a"), paramB = Expression.Parameter(type, "b");
  BinaryExpression addExpression = Expression.Add(paramA, paramB);
  var add = Expression.Lambda(addExpression, paramA, paramB).Compile();
  var v = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
  add.DynamicInvoke(v, v);
  return true;
}
catch
{
  return false;
}
}
```

and  IsAveragable function (what a weird name:) )

```
public bool IsAveragable(Type type)
try
{
  ParameterExpression paramA = Expression.Parameter(type, "a"), paramB = Expression.Parameter(type, "b");
        // add the parameters together
        BinaryExpression addExpression = Expression.Add(paramA, paramB);
        var avg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "b");
        var conv  = Expression.Convert(avg,type);
        BinaryExpression divideExpression = Expression.Divide(paramA, conv);
        // compile it
        var add = Expression.Lambda(addExpression, paramA, paramB).Compile();
        var divide = Expression.Lambda(divideExpression, paramA, avg).Compile();
        var v = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        add.DynamicInvoke(v, v);
        divide.DynamicInvoke(v, 1);
                    return true;
}
catch
{
  return false;
}
}
```

part of the code taken from MiscUtil by Marc Gravell

Answer (score 1):

Actually, for min/max it is easier to use `Comparer<T>.Default`, which also supports `IComparable<T>`, handles "lifted" operators, etc.

You can get most of this for free if you use [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/); I wrote some code that provides access to generic operators, including generic extension methods for `Sum`, `Average`, etc. Unfortunately, operators can't appear on interfaces, and to make things worse the primitives don't *actually* have operators in the `MethodInfo` sense (this is provided directly in IL instead) - [as discussed here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html).

Comment: Can I expect that if Type implements  + and - operators it is summable.

Comment: @Sergey - with the implementation cited above, yes: adding + is enough to make it summable (although it also supports the inbuilt types like `int` which *don't* (as explained) truly have operators). Adding + and a /(int) would make it possible to use `Average`.

Comment: hm, but what to do with simple types as short, byte, uint, long etc?

Comment: @Sergey - If you use the MiscUtil code, it handles them for you. The code is available for download, so you can see how it does it, or it is discussed on the "as discussed here" page.

Comment: @Marc Gravell thank you for info about lifted operators I never expect such a thing typeof(IComparable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(int?))==false.

now my dynamic comparer uses Comparer<T>
var type = typeof (int?);
int f = 0;
int? s = 0;
var comparer = typeof(Comparer<>).MakeGenericType(type);
var d = comparer.GetProperty("Default").GetValue(null, BindingFlags.Static, null, null, null);
var equals = comparer.GetMethod("Compare").Invoke(d, new object[] {f, s})==0;

Comment: @Sergey - that will be slow as treacle; if you don't know the type, use the non-generic `Comparer.Default.Compare(x,y)`. And for equals, just use `object.Equals(x,y)`